# Luxon not running in stackblitz with typescript

Tags: stackblitz, luxon

I'm trying to make a luxon example in stackblitz, but the imports are not working.

The luxon library and its types are added, and it is imported at the beginning of the file:
[image: appDiv.innerHTML = luxon sample -->"${DateTime.now()}"<--;]

However I get the message that it is undefined!

I tried to find other examples of stackblitz (google: "luxon stackblitz") however none of them seem to work or use and old version, which is imported via CDN

Do I somehow have to add the whole luxon library to the project?

Code (super simple)

```
// Import stylesheets
import './style.css';
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';

// Write TypeScript code!
const appDiv: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('app');
appDiv.innerHTML = `luxon sample -->"${DateTime.now()}"<--`;
```

Comment: Note: I found a ts-luxon library, but the last update there is 5 months old... https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-agvh7w?file=index.ts

Comment: If the ts-luxon library is 2.0.1, the only thing you are missing is "fix locale defaulting" from 2.0.2

Comment: That library actually seems to run with luxon 1.25.0 :/